# In a table, see if an ID has a row for each minute in a day - how to optimize this query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to show a table, for each ID, to see if there is data available. In this case, it's measurements. If there's no data, that means the logger isn't doing its job properly.

I currently have two tables: `data` and `times`. `data` contains `id`, `datetime`, `sensor_id`, and `value`. `times` contains `id` and `value`.

Times is filled with `00:00`, `00:01`, `00:02` etcetera, all the way through to `23:59`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT t.`value`, d.`sensor_id`, COUNT(t.`value`) as `numrows`
FROM `data` d
RIGHT JOIN `times` t
ON d.`datetime` LIKE CONCAT('% ', t.`value`, '%')
WHERE d.`datetime` LIKE '%$2014-11-05%'
AND d.`sensor_id` IN(1,2,3,4,5,999)
GROUP BY d.`sensor_id`, t.`value`
ORDER BY d.`sensor_id` ASC, t.`id` ASC

while($s = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
    $checkArray[$s['sensor_id']][$s['value']] = $s['numrows'];
}

foreach($checkArray as $key => $arr) {
    echo 'Sensor: ' . $key;
    for($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j <= 59; $j++) {
            $time = strlen($i) == 1 ? '0' . $i : '' . $i;
            $time .= ':';
            $time .= strlen($j) == 1 ? '0' .$j : '' . $j;

            if(isset($arr[$time]) && $arr[$time] >= 1) { //See if has at least one row
                echo 'YES DATA FOR ' . $time . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I sort this in a table, and the result is this:

[image: Result]

Just for sensors 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, the load time is over 5.5 seconds. I don't know how to optimize this further. I've put indexes on the queried columns, but I can't think of anything else.

My `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `data`:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
 `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sensor_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
 `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `value` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `sensor_id_2` (`sensor_id`,`datetime`,`value`),
 KEY `sensor_id` (`sensor_id`),
 KEY `value` (`value`),
 KEY `datetime` (`datetime`),
 KEY `sensor_id_3` (`sensor_id`),
 KEY `datetime_2` (`datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=103921 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please show your indexes in the database tables. Try `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html Having the correct indexes might help a lot. This would be an excelent question for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I made an oopsie with the naming in my question - the column name inside `times` is indeed `value`. Added my `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to the question (bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work off of your query:

```
SELECT t.value, d.sensor_id, COUNT(t.value) as numrows
FROM times t LEFT JOIN
     data d
     ON date_format(d.datetime, '%H:%i') = t.value
WHERE d.datetime >= date('2014-11-05') and
      d.datetime < date('2014-11-06') and
      d.sensor_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 999)
GROUP BY d.sensor_id, t.value
ORDER BY d.sensor_id ASC, t.value ASC;
```

Note in particular that this query does not use `like` on date/time columns.  That forces them to convert to strings and precludes the use of indexes.

Comment: This is perfect and does the job amazingly fast. Thanks, great answer!

Comment: I think it might be better to remove the `order by` section, as it isn't helping much and may only slow the query down.

Comment: @iLot . . . http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/21/heads-up-implicit-sorting-by-group-by-is-deprecated-in-mysql-5-6.html.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is going to struggle as it is trying to do a join on a LIKE with a leading wildcard. No index will be useful for this.

Further you check the value of datetime in the WHERE clause, again with a leading wildcard which will prevent indexes being used on that check. Further you are checking a value on the RIGHT JOINed table, effectively rendering it an INNER JOIN.

I would try something like this:-

```
SELECT sub0.aDateTime, sub1.sensor_id, COUNT(d.datetime)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-11-05 00:00:00', INTERVAL a.Mnt + b.Mnt * 10 + c.Mnt * 100 + d.Mnt * 1000 MINUTE) AS aDateTime,
            DATE_ADD('2014-11-05 00:00:59', INTERVAL a.Mnt + b.Mnt * 10 + c.Mnt * 100 + d.Mnt * 1000 MINUTE) AS aDateTimeEnd
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1) d
    WHERE (a.Mnt + b.Mnt * 10 + c.Mnt * 100 + d.Mnt * 1000) < 1440
) sub0
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 1 AS sensor_id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 999) sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN data d
ON d.datetime BETWEEN sub0.aDateTime AND sub0.aDateTimeEnd
AND d.sensor_id = sub1.sensor_id
GROUP BY sub1.sensor_id, sub0.aDateTime
ORDER BY sub1.sensor_id ASC, sub0.aDateTime ASC
```

This is generating a range of numbers from 0 to 1439 (ie, number of minutes in a day) and adding that to the start of the day you are interested in. This is so generating a row for each minute of the day (the 2 date / time values returned are for the first and last seconds of the minute). It then LEFT OUTER JOINs the data to that based on the date_time.

This could be easily improved if you just have a table of the number 1 to 1439 and join that against the data to save the sub query (it would still need a function to calculate the dates, but still saves a bit of time).

Comment: Great comment, thanks! Query is erroring on `SELECT 0 FROM Mnt` part, though: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT ' at line 6`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there's a comma too much left from the `from`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, thanks. There's also `BETWEEB` instead of `BETWEEN`. Regardless, this query takes over 45 seconds. `Showing rows 0 - 24 (7187 total, Query took 45.2706 sec)`, so not faster at all :(.

Comment: Check it is using indexes (do an explain). I would expect it to use the sensor_id_2 index. Something strange is happening as it should return a multiple of 1440 rows, not 7187 rows.

Comment: That can be cleaned up using a table of values from 0 to 1439. I have amended the query to select a sensor_id to come out with the right number of row. This is cross joining against another sub query but if you have a table of sensors it would be better to join against that (ie, _INNER JOIN sensors ON sensor_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,999)_ )